# Where's root_path or root_url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In rails, there are a lot of helpers to direct our actions, like `collections_path` `new_member_path` `edit_member_path` and so on.

But where is the root? Is there a helper always points to my homepage?

Comment: It will be listed when you do `rake routes` at the command prompt.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

These helpers exist, but you have to set your root url before, in `config/routes.rb`:

```
root :to => "controller#action"
```

You can use `root_url` and `root_path` afterwards.

Be warned that there's a catch when doing redirections with the `_path` helpers, you should use the `_url` ones when redirecting (see @LanguagesNamedAfterCoffee's comment for the details).

Comment: Just remember that whenever you are using `redirect_to` you will have to use `root_url`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know that. Out of curiosity: what does this breaks? It simply doesn't work or breaks something else (back button, etc)?

Comment: The HTTP spec requires a fully qualified URL when doing 302 Redirect and friends, and it will work in some lenient browsers, but _path should not be used. (from Agile Web Development with Rails)

Comment: Thanks for the precision, I posted an addendum in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It helped me since I used redirect_to root_path and it didn't work. 
In config\routes.rb, I changed 
root: 'home#index' 
to 
root :to => 'home#index'

Comment: root_path vs root_url. As it turns out, _path only returns the url relative to your domain.

For instance, root_path returns / while root_url returns http://example.com/.